# How to pass user permissions from Yii2 to Angular

Tags: angularjs, yii2

I have web application that uses Yii2 as API and Angular for frontend stuff. I am wondering, what would be best way to pass user permissions from Yii2 to Angular so i can show / hide data per user permissions.

My first idea was to make a api call for that data before angular starts and than use that data inside angular.
I see this as a problem if user permissions change while user is working. Users data would refresh only when he refreshes whole page which is not so often in Angular.

My second idea was to push permission data to user with every API request, but i dont know how to do it.
Any ideas?

Comment: i'm faced this problem, i solve this problem using user role related special tokens and it's work fine and securely

Comment: How did you implement them?

Comment: So you can use angular token based authentication. Simply u use api for that. Create for  checking every api request and aslo login with angular. I created e.g  called starter  module : angular.module('starter')
 
.constant('AUTH_EVENTS', {
  notAuthenticated: 'auth-not-authenticated',
  notAuthorized: 'auth-not-authorized'
})
 
.constant('USER_ROLES', {
  admin: 'admin',
  user: 'user'
});  And also u must write services for that.